# Need help to identify potentiometers, please

Tags: identification, potentiometer

I have to replace some scratchy potentiometers used as volume potentiometers in a *Rocktron Velocity 300* guitar power amp from the early 1990's.

These two parts are labelled:

- 15A100K 9252
- TØB10K 9303

Does someone have some informations about them or a source where I can get information?

Edit: I've found schematics for the Velocity 300:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sometimes the markings can be a bit different, but if you look at the following related question first is probably a 100K logarithmic and second is probably a 10K linear (but you'll see the codes have changed over time) http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75840/potentiometer-codes

Comment: Hi PeterJ, this is a possible answer. I've found schematics containing a 10K linear pot an a 100K pot, which defaults most probably to be logarithmic.

Comment: As the B in the 10k one means 'linear', the A in the 100k one means 'Audio' i.e. 'logarithmic'. See [here](http://www.resistorguide.com/potentiometer-taper/) for markings.

Answer (score 2):

A-scale pots are "audio" scale, which is sort-of logarithmic.  That's your 100k pot.

B-scale pots are linear, i.e. uniform track width.  That's your 10k pot.

See this [reference on pots](https://sound-au.com/pots.htm) including markings.

The arrows on the schematic tell you which way they're physically oriented; I think the arrow indicates motion of the wiper with clockwise rotation but am not sure about that.